# Did join() frees allocated memory? - C++11 Threads

Tags: c++, c++11

Imagine that I use `C++11 threads`. The thread will run a function that do `malloc`. After that I will use `join` without `free` (the memory). So, I killed the thread. It is expected that the memory frees automatically?

Comment: It would be impossible to write sane code if this was the case. You'd have to carefully keep track of which thread owned which objects and couldn't terminate a thread until you were done with everything it allocated. That would make library design, umm, interesting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not. The memory is freed only after the whole application is terminated. The whole benefit of using multiple threads (as opposed to processes) is that they share the same memory, so they collectively own all the memory allocated in one of them.